# Does the new RestClient introduced in Spring Framework 6.1 have a variant suitable for testing like RestTemplate had with TestRestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

In spring framework 6.1, a new synchronous HTTP client `RestClient` was introduced. See also:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29552

It aims to replace the existing `RestTemplate`.

In Spring Boot, there was a `TestRestTemplate` which could be used for integration tests. See also:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.utilities.test-rest-template

However, I could not find any mention of a variant for `RestClient`. What is the recommended way to do integration testing using `RestClient` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no test variant of `RestClient`. [This Spring Framework issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31275) is tracking a `RestClient` equivalent of `WebClient`'s `WebTestClient`.